# Changes in ui:include page are only refreshed after a couple of minutes

Tags: jsf, caching, facelets, uiinclude

I have a page with a kind of "pop-up" in the bottom:

```
<p:outputPanel id="updatePanel" styleClass="updatePanel bordered">
    <ui:include src="file:///C:/.DS/include/update.xhtml" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

but when the contents of that file are changed, the page does not, even when I refresh it like 10 times.

In a couple of minutes though, I refresh the page and it works nicely.

Is that some kind of cache problem or something?

**Update**

I un-accepted the answer, since apparently it has nothing to do with cache, I deleted cache (Ctrl+Shift+Del), and yet, the changes in the file still are not reflected on the page. Moreover, my `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` param is set to `Development`.